# AWS CONSOLE Can I use a user that is not in my org

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Can I give a user that I did not create permissions to aws resources? for example I have an s3 bucket that I want to give permissions to someone with an already existing AWS account. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the AWS console it requires the IAM entity be within that account, even if someone has an AWS account it will not be granted access to login to someone else's account.

Instead certain services will support the ability to access the resources tie to your account from an IAM entity in their account. In your example of S3 you can allow either an explicit IAM entity or the entirety of another AWS account access by granting permissions in the [Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-language-overview.html) specifying these accounts in the principal.

More information is available in [How can I provide cross-account access to objects that are in Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/) documentation.